# MySQL - count value returns 1 when should be 0

Tags: mysql, sql

The following SQL is from a video-based online courses system. The query brings up a course instance, for a given user, and also brings up info on which videos of the course he or she has or hasn't yet watched.

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        COALESCE(watches.num_watches, 0) ORDER BY cvi.position
    ) AS watches_per_vid
FROM course_instances tci
LEFT JOIN videos 
    ON tci.node IN (
       SELECT node_id 
       FROM _taxonomy_assocs 
       WHERE item_id = videos.id
    )
LEFT JOIN course_indexes cvi 
    ON videos.vimeo_id = cvi.vimeo_id 
    && cvi.course_id = tci.node
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT watches.vid_id, SUM(times) as num_watches
    FROM watches
    GROUP BY watches.vid_id
) watches 
   ON watches.vid_id = videos.id
WHERE tci.user = "vgaz1kjbc65" 
&& node = "jmi_gmoan26" #<-- for example
GROUP BY tci.id
```

For `watches_per_vid`, this results in, for example,

```
4,4,5,2,2,2,1
```

However I'm finding that even if a user hasn't yet watched a video - which means there is no entry in the `watches` table for this user and video, it produces 1, not 0.

Here is the watches table:

```
field           | type         | null   | default            | extra
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id (primary)      varchar(11)    n
user_id           varchar(11)    n
vid_id            varchar(11)    n
latest_stamp      timestamp      n        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
times             int(11)        n        1
```

Can anyone see why this might be happening? I can of course provide more structural code if required.

Comment: I don't see in watches how you're limiting by user either on the join or in the group by.  So as a result if ANYONE has watched the video, a record is returned.

Comment: Thank you. Rookie error in the extreme. See comment below answer.

Comment: Meh, we all have those days/moments and sometimes another pair of eyes is all it takes.

Answer (score 3):

There's no link to the user in the watches table that I see.  You're getting the number of times each video has been watched (by anyone) for all videos linked to courses that user is taking.

If you want the number of times that use rhas watched a video, you need to change

```
SELECT watches.vid_id, SUM(times) as num_watches
FROM watches
GROUP BY watches.vid_id
```

into

```
SELECT watches.vid_id, SUM(times) as num_watches
FROM watches
WHERE watches.user_id = tci.user
GROUP BY watches.vid_id
```

Comment: or add to the join criteria instead of correlating:   `ON watches.vid_id = videos.id and watches.user_ID = tci.user` and add the user_ID to `select and group by`.

Comment: The answer produced the error "unknown column, tci.users", presumably because it can't read the outside scope. +1 for the notion, though, since you still identified the problem (along with @xQbert). Altering the join criteria, instead, worked. Thank you both.

Comment: odd... I thought mySQL supported correlated queries. it's not more than 1 level deep so correlation should work; but happy we could help.